# Suppose that $R$ is a ring and $a,b\in R$. Prove that if $a+b = ab$, then $ab=ba$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Suppose that $R$ is a ring and $a,b\in R$. Prove that if $a+b = ab$, then $ab=ba$.

I think for this problem because we are given that $a,b$ are elements of the ring we need to show that $a$ and $b$ are invertible. However, in this particular case I don't really know how to do it using $a+b=ab$.

Comment: Please don't post images just to capture a few formulas: instead, use MathJax to transcribe the formulas into your post.

Answer (score 5):

The statement as given does not seem to be true.  For a counterexample, let $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ denote the Abelian group of sequences of integers, and let $R$ be the ring of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ (with multiplication given by composition).  Now define two elements
$$a, (x_1, x_2, \ldots) \mapsto (x_1 + x_2, x_2 + x_3, x_3 + x_4, \ldots), \\
b, (x_1, x_2, \ldots) \mapsto (x_1, x_1 + x_2, x_2 + x_3, \ldots).$$
Then $ab = a + b$ (both map $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ to $(2x_1 + x_2, x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3, x_2 + 2x_3 + x_4, \ldots$), but $ab \ne ba$ (since $ba$ maps $(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ to $(x_1 + x_2, x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3, x_2 + 2x_3 + x_4, \ldots)$).

Comment: Got it. I misread the question

Comment: The idea (I assume) for this counterexample comes from the fact that we can observe that $(a-1)(b-1) = 1$, so taking $x = a -1$ and $y = b-1$ we want to find a unital ring with elements $x$ and $y$ satisfying $xy = 1$, but not $yx = 1$. The shift operators $(x_1, \dots ) \mapsto (0, x_1, \dots)$ and $(x_1, \dots ) \mapsto (x_2, \dots)$ are classical examples of this. Another example comes from formal integration and differentiation on polynomials, giving $a(p) := p + p'$, $b(p) = p + \int p$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the idea.

Comment: It might be worth observing that the statement *is* true in the case that $R$ is the matrix ring $M_n(k)$ for some field $k$, essentially because in that ring, $AB = I_n \implies BA = I_n$.